# Can I edit the values in an access report using vba?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table, tblCustomers, where I want to build a report from it. However, I was told that they would like to enter addresses in this format: YYYYMMDD (20170311 for March 11, 2017). However, within the report they would like the date to be expressed in this format MM DD, YYYY (March 11, 2017). Is this even possible to change the formatting of values for a report when the recordset, to my understanding is a read only option. I am attempting other solutions but would like to know if I could add some vba code to report.load event that would change the date as requested. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even report is readonly, the recordsource can be re-read (after editing the underlying table data)!. But no need for that, if you store the date as`Datetime` (a double (fraction is time,integer is days since 1899-12-31), internally) not as string!. Now you can format as you like in the query.

```vb
Select Format(DateField,"mmm d.yyyy") As FormattedDate ....
```

Read [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications?f1url=https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=de-DE&k=k(vblr6.chm1008925);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version=v15)&rd=true) Docs forformat options.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up not needing this as further working on the database I saw that they only print forms and not reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to filter on a date entered as YYYYMMDD, you can filter the query that you use as source for the report this way:

```sql
Select * 
From YourTable 
Where YourDateField = DateValue(Format([Enter Date as YYYYMMDD], "@@@@/@@/@@"))
```